# How to modify object and struct from an existing struct?

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct say

```
type person struct{
    name string
    phone string
    address string
}
```

and I want to transform it to this (modify phone and address) *I only have the object not the struct.*

```
type person2 struct {
    name  string
    phone []struct {
        value string
    }

    address []struct {
        value string
    }
}
```

How can I create new struct based on one I have ? I want to transform selected fields only.

I looked into reflection but don't know where to start/how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Foreword:** if you only have the type `person` and not `person2`, you have to first write `person2`. Go is statically typed language, you can't just create `person2` at runtime. You may write `person2` manually or use `go generate` by writing the generator code yourself, but it won't be any simpler.

You could also use something like `map[string]interface{}` to *mimic* a dynamic struct, but that won't be any friendlier nor faster. Not to mention you'd have to use type assertions as value type is `interface{}`...

---

To create a value of `person2` from a value of `person`, you don't need reflection, you can simply manually code it:

```
func transform(p person) person2 {
    return person2{
        p.name,
        []struct{ value string }{{p.phone}},
        []struct{ value string }{{p.address}},
    }
}
```

Note that this may look a little weird, and that's because you used a slice of anonymous struct for `person2.phone` and `person2.address`, and to initialize an anonymous struct with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals), the anonymous struct definition has to be repeated.

Testing it:

```
p := person{"Bob", "1234", "New York"}
fmt.Println(p)
p2 := transform(p)
fmt.Println(p2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/zg2Izw5Fy1)):

```
{Bob 1234 New York}
{Bob [{1234}] [{New York}]}
```

**Note:**

Note that your `person2` is unnecessarily complex. It could be as simple as this:

```
type person2 struct {
    name      string
    phones    []string
    addresses []string
}
```

And then the transformation is a one-liner:

```
func transform(p person) person2 {
    return person2{p.name, []string{p.phone}, []string{p.address}}
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Q3Or7RAjNH)):

```
{Bob 1234 New York}
{Bob [1234] [New York]}
```

Comment: I don't have Person2, I need to generate it first using Person. It is mostly same as Person except for few fields which need to be transformed.

Comment: @user568109 If you don't have `person2` (yet) but you do have `person`, then you have to first write `person2`. Go is statically typed. You can't just create new types during runtime.

Comment: The struct I use is big so I will have to use the generate tool. Any pointers on how to use that.

Comment: @user568109 If you just have to do it once, no matter how big the struct is, you're better off doing it manually. `go generate` comes handy when you have to do such task repeatedly and for many different inputs.

Comment: For now I will try that. generate is long term solution because I don't control the original struct itself and it is difficult to get it working.